# CKeditor not working on CreateVIew in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-ckeditor

I've installed **CKeditor** and apply it to the **models.py**. I run the migrations and migrate it to DB. I tried to test it by going to the admin page. I can see that **CKeditor** is showing, but when I render it to my **template** using **CreateView**, it does not show.

**Models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from ckeditor.fields import RichTextField


class Content(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    content = RichTextField(blank=True, null=True)
    date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    website = models.URLField()
    github = models.URLField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_image_filename,
                              verbose_name='Image')
```

**Forms.py**

```
class ContentForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Content
        fields = [
            'title',
            'content',
            'website',
            'github',
            'image',
        ]
```

**Views.py**

```
class CreateContentView(CreateView):
    form_class = ContentForm
    template_name = 'appOne/create_content.html'
```

**Template**

```
<form method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.text | safe }}
    {{ form.media }}
    <input type="submit" value="Save">
</form>
```

The weird thing is, in the Admin Page, the CKeditor works totally fine, but when I passed it to the template, the toolbar and menubar are not showing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as the code from their github https://github.com/django-ckeditor/django-ckeditor#outside-of-django-admin yor form should look like

```
from ckeditor.widgets import CKEditorWidget

class ContentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    content = forms.CharField(widget=CKEditorWidget())
    class Meta:
        model = Content
        fields = [
            'title',
            'content',
            'website',
            'github',
            'image',
        ]
```

and your template

```
<form>
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.text | safe }}
    {{ myform.media }}
    {{ myform.as_p }}
     <input type="submit" value="Save">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this in **forms.py**:

```
from ckeditor.widgets import CKEditorWidget
class ContentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    content = forms.CharField(widget=CKEditorWidget())
    class Meta:
        model = Content
        fields = '__all__'
```

In **template**:

```
<form>
    {{ form.media }}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

[Reference Link](https://pypi.org/project/django-ckeditor/#widget)